# Using private functions as callbacks in revealing prototype pattern

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming, revealing-prototype

I am using revealing prototype pattern as follows:

```
var myClass = function () {
    var that = this;

    // private member : An instance of another class which requires some private 
    // members of myClass to be passed as callbacks in its parameters
    this.externalClassInstance = new externalClass({
        callbackName: function () {
            myClass.prototype.myFunction.call(that);
        }
    });
};

myClass.prototype = function () {
    // myFunction remains a private member until I define it in the return statement to make it public
    var myFunction = function () {
        alert("hello");
    };
    return {
    // Uncommenting the next line would make the code work but would also make myFunction public
    //            myFunction : myFunction
    };
}();

var externalClass = function (data) {
       data.callbackName(); 
};

var myClassInstance = new myClass();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3a7MW/

The code above does not work since I have not made `myFunction` as public.
This is because `myFunction` being used only as a callback would always run in the scope of `myClass` and I do not want anybody having the myClass object to invoke the constructor.

**How to make this code work without making the `myFunction` public?**

One way I understand is the have the myFunction as private variable of the class(by defining it in constructor) instead of a prototype. Is there another better solution?

Comment: Your intention is not clear. Can you reduce your example to a even simpler one?>

Comment: I added some comments. I am trying to have a private method of a class  being passed as a callback to another class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using that pattern, I would go with the module pattern to encapsulate your private functions:

```
(function(ns) {

function myFunction()
{
  alert('hello');
}

ns.myClass = function()
{
  var that = this;

  this.externalClassInstance = new externalClass({
      callbackName: function () {
          myFunction.call(that);
      }
  });
}

}(window));
```

Comment: module pattern does not provide us the benefits of having prototypes. Memory optimization.

Comment: @Divij It's not much of a prototype if the method in question should be hidden, that's not what prototypes are for. I don't get the memory optimisation either, because the private function in this case is only declared once.